# Arduino print Syntax Serial << '[' << RSP_SUCCESS << ']' << endl;

Tags: printing, syntax, arduino

I am working on Io Rodeo Colorimeter sensor board I get an Arduino code and when I see the Arduino code then I find:

```
Serial << '[' << RSP_SUCCESS;
Serial << ',' << _DEC(colorimeter.frequency.red);
Serial << ',' << _DEC(colorimeter.frequency.green);
Serial << ',' << _DEC(colorimeter.frequency.blue);
Serial << ',' << _DEC(colorimeter.frequency.white);
```

this type of syntax I think this is print syntax but programme cannot print anything?

Answer (score 0):

Neat, didn't even thing about using streams in arduino.

In C++(that is what the Arduino language is, mostly), you can define(and in the most common case it's defined by default) a << operator, that is meant to format data to a stream, commonly used for input and output.

In C++, it's usually used like this:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
int variableA = 10;
std::cout << "Value of a variable variableA" << " is " << variableA << std::endl;
}
```

The above code would result in outputing "Value of a variable variableA is 10" to the console(standard output).

In the case of arduino, the streaming operator can be defined for the "Serial" object.

There is an article about it here: https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/StreamingOutput
The streaming operator described here is templated to allow for different data types to be passed to the Serial.print(...) function.